# The meaning of ios:: in std::ios::fixed

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
using namespace std;

cout.setf(ios::fixed);
cout.precision(2);
```

The above codes are used to round the output to the 2 decimal places.

I am not very familiar to the library thingy. What is the meaning of `ios::` written before the `fixed`? Why do we need to add `ios::` instead of typing `fixed`? In other words, can anyone explain the meaning of `std::ios::fixed` and if I use `std::fixed`, that would be wrong? `ios::` is not a `namespace`, right?

Comment: it is a namespace. a namespace within a namespace.

Comment: @ChrisBeck, It's an easy mistake to make, but it's a class (...template specialization) rather than a namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ios` is a `typedef`...

```
typedef basic_ios<char> ios;
```

...which specifies a `basic_ios` instantiation to handle operations on `char` types.

So, for example, `std::ios::`*X* works for `char`, while `std::basic_ios<wchar_t>::`*X* aka `std::wios::`*X* works for "wide" characters (e.g. capable of encoding more symbols / non-English languages etc.).  In the case of *X*==`fixed`, they're the same constant inherited from [`std::ios_base`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base)'s [`fmtflags`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags), but the freedom is there for the implementation to do whatever's best to support those different *char_type*s in the members that aren't inherited from the common base, such as `.good()`, `.eof()`, `.clear()`, `fill()`, `narrow()` etc. - see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios).

For convenience, you can simply use `cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << my_data...;`, rather than directly calling `cout.setf` with the flag values.

Comment: They *have to* be the same constant; there is no implementation freedom.

Comment: I was about to say a typedef doesn't instantiate anything, then I realised it probably instantiates the template, then doesn't instantiate the instantiated template. (Gee, overloaded words can be confusing!)

Answer (score 1):

`ios` is an alias for `basic_ios<char>`. `ios::fixed` refers to a member constant of that class called `fixed`, which it actually inherits from the class `ios_base`, which is a common base class for all iostream classes, so all of `ios_base::fixed`, `ios::fixed`, `fstream::fixed`, `istringstream::fixed`, and `cout.fixed` refer to the same thing.

`std::fixed` is a manipulator that sets the `fixed` flag when used on a stream like `stream << std::fixed`, provided for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

`fixed` exists both as a manipulator (a function) in namespace `std`, but also as a `static constexpr fmtflags` in `std::ios_base`. `std::ios` is just a typedef for `std::basic_ios<char>`, which in turn is derived from `std::ios_base`. In other words, it inherits the member variable `fixed`.  Note that the manipulator does what you do manually:

```
// Same as std::cout << std::fixed 
std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield);
```